# Intercept executed commands in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I need to know is it possible to intercept user executed command in loadable kernel module. I know that system calls can be intercepted such as open(). But what i need to do is intercepts user entered command/ process and add some validations. for example, if user enters cp command, before executing the command i need to perform some validations against it. If we cannot do this in LKM, what are the alternative approaches?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look up how many actual system calls there are for [`execvp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) and friends (probably 1, maybe 2 — it could be more, but probably isn't), and then intercept those system calls. You might need to worry about [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) and friends too.  They're the only ways that new processes can be run.  There isn't any other way to intercept them.

Comment: thnx @Jonnathan Leffler, but i still don't understand this. in order to check how many system calls, still need to intercept the current process right? Ho

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an LKM or a systemtap plugin(which compiles to an LKM). The kernel functions that you should hook are [execve](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/exec.c#L1910) and [execveat](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/exec.c#L1918). In case you are doing this for programming fun and want to write hooking code by yourself, you might want to look at [kprobes](https://lwn.net/Articles/132196/) and know that you can get kernel function addresses from `/proc/kallsyms`.

Of course, recompiling the kernel with your own hooking code is another option if that is a possibility.

In both the cases above you probably want to intercept the execve calls made by a specific uid; if so, you should filter calls from that uid.

A userspace approach might be to try writing a seccomp filter. [Here](https://outflux.net/teach-seccomp/) is a tutorial on how to go about writing one.